# Remove dulplicate Value from array in vb?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, duplicates

i have a array like

```
arr(0) = {jan,jan,feb,feb,feb,mar,mar,mar,apr,apr}
```

How can  i  count the number of each value and  remove the  duplicate the value  ?

Comment: Perhaps posting the desired output & some selfwritten code might help us to determine exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: i want the out put like   {jan,feb,mar,apr}            then the no of occourance of jan,feb,mar,apr,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Dim grouping = arr.GroupBy(Function(x) x).Select(Function(g) New With {g.Key, Key .Count = g.Count()})

For Each g In grouping
    Console.WriteLine(g.Key & ":" & g.Count)
Next

Dim distinctList = grouping.Select(Function(x) x.Key)

For Each item In distinctList
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

To counting the number of each value:

`arr(0).Length`

To removing the duplicated element:

```vb
Public Sub RemoveDuplications(Of T)(ByRef arr() As T)
    Dim filteredList As List(Of T) = New List(Of T)

    For Each element As T In arr

        ' If element is already added in the list, skip the elementi
        If filteredList.Contains(element) Then Continue For

        ' Add element to the list
        filteredList.Add(element)
    Next

    ' Return filtered array
    arr = filteredList.ToArray()
End Sub
```

Usage:

`RemoveDuplications(Of Integer)(a(0))` or `RemoveDuplications(Of Your_Array_Type)(Array_Variable)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create two temporary arrays; one `int "arri" (def value 0)` and one `string "arrs" (def value "")` with a dim of your arr

I pseudocode it

```
for int iStart = 0 to arr.count
     dim findIT as integer
      for findIT = 0 to arrs.count
          if (arrs(findIT ) = "") then
            arrs(findIT ) = arr(iStart)
            arri(findIT ) = arri(findIT )+1
            exit for
          else if (arrs(findIT ) = arr(iStart)) then
            arri(findIT ) = arri(findIT )+1
            exit for
          end if
      next
next

for int iShow = 0 to arrs.count
    if (Not(arrs(findIT ) = "")) then
        'print arrs(findIT ) has arri(findIT ) occurrences
    else
       exit for
    end if
next
```